# can't reduce Bitmap resolution

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Hello this question might be a little long but i'm going to explain everything for not 
getting the same codes i already tried 
i got an app inside of it there's a button contents:

```
try{

Intent Intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this , TheSsecondClass2.class);
Intent1.putExtra("bitmapsent", ImageMap); // from user gallery or camera 
startActivityForResult(Intent1, 3);
}
```

then the app makes "in the new activity" `imageview` equals `ImageMap` and scales the `Imageview` using the code:

```
Captured.setImageBitmap(ImageMap);
    Captured.getLayoutParams().height = 1400;
    Captured.getLayoutParams().width = 1200;
```

then the user  edits it a little bit then when he finish it uses button that returns the `RESULT_OK` and it's code:

```
            overlay(Background, currentleft, currentright, currentTop,currentBottom);
//          getting things back when the safr"startactivityforresult" starts

            Intent IntentBack = new Intent(TheSsecondClass2.this , MainActivity.class);
            IntentBack.putExtra("returnedbitmap", bmOverlay);
            IntentBack.putExtras(IntentBack);
            setResult(RESULT_OK , IntentBack);
            finish();
```

the `overlay` method returns bitmap `bmoverlay` is a mixture of bitmaps for editing purposes like editing left,right 
bottom,top and the background or the main picture the issue that bitmaps merge to one image and everything is fine but the problem
that when it's back the bitmap is getting bigger and off the edges of the image view even when adding it to gallery i tried to scale it using:

```
                ScaledBit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ImageMap, 1, 1, true);
            ScaledBit = ImageMap;
```

and used -1 or bigger numbers but it's like making it thousand times bigger or so .
and tried the the two codes below:

```
    CapturedImage.setMaxHeight(200);
            CapturedImage.setMaxHeight(200);
            Bitmap.setwidth();
            Bitmap.setHeight();
```

i might used more but i forgot about it ,all the variables are declared are below :

```
Bitmap ImageMap;
ImageView CapturedImage;
static Bitmap currentright,currentleft,currentTop,currentBottom;
static Bitmap bmOverlay ,background;
```

api level 11.
please help and thanks btw.

Comment: You create ScaledBit, then immediately overwrite it?

Comment: This: ScaledBit = ImageMap; You've just overwritten your previous ScaledBit with the original ImageMap